# Try to compare start & end date with mm/yyyy format

Tags: jquery, date, validation

i write this with help of other user from here, but not working.

I've got two field, with maskedinput from here > http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ in this format : mm/yyyy

I want to compare end date to be greater than start, and disable submit button if is not. But i always want for user, they could register a form without inform a start or end date.
So i just want to compare this two fields when they've got 7 characters inside, and 
function have to be done in this > yyyymm because with mmyyyy they're is no chance to works fine.

Do you have any idea to suggest to me ?

Thanks in advance for any help ;)

HTML

```
<form class="blockdate">
    <input name="stardate"type="text" class="date"/>
    <input name="enddate" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="date"/>
</form>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

JS

```
var compareA = getElementsByName("startdate");
var comparen = getElementsByName("enddate");
function compare() {
// Assumes the format mm/yyyy (not mmyyyy, which your example values seem to be in)
var compareA, compareB;
compareA = dateA.substring(3) + dateA.substring(0, 2);
compareB = dateB.substring(3) + dateB.substring(0, 2);
if (compareA > compareB) {
       $('#msg').html('Check Stard & Endate.');
        $(".submit").prop("disabled",true);

}
}


    jQuery(function($) {

         $('.blockdate').submit(function() {
          return compare;
       });

        $(".date").change(function(){
          if(datevalue2.length == 7) {
            compare;
          } else {
            clean();
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What part of this is not working? Does any of it work? Do you get an error message? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: Hello DOK,
nothing happen, i'm not very familiar with JS

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `enddate` doesnt have the class `date` assigned to it. So youre never gonna grab that value. Secondly, if you need to reverse the order of the month year, then just swap the substring calls:

```
//         month                   year
compareA = dateA.substring(0, 2) + dateA.substring(3);

//         year                   month
compareA = dateA.substring(3) + dateA.substring(0,2);
```

Lastly you should jsut use the `Date` object to get a unix timestamp which is a real integer version of a given date you can use for comparison:

```
function compare(start, end) {

  var start, 
    end,
    toDate = function(datestr){
        return new Date(parseInt(datestr.substring(3)), parseInt(datestr.substring(0, 2)));
    };

    if(toDate(start).getTime() > toDate(end).getTime()) {
        $('#msg').html('Check Stard & Endate.');
        $(".submit").prop("disabled",true);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **prodigitalson** answered, your code should be like this

HTML

```
<form class="blockdate">
<input name="stardate"type="text" id="dateA" class="date"/>
<input name="enddate" type="text" id="dateB" class="date"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="btnOk"/>
</form>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

JS

```
function compare(start, end) {

    var start, end, toDate = function(datestr) {
        return new Date(parseInt(datestr.substring(3)), parseInt(datestr.substring(0, 2)));
    };

    if (toDate(start).getTime() > toDate(end).getTime()) {
        $('#msg').html('Check Stard & Endate.');
        $(".submit").prop("disabled", true);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function clean() {
    $('#msg').html('');
    $("#btnOk").removeAttr("disabled");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnOk').click(function(e) {
        if (!compare()) e.preventDefault();
        return true;
    });

    $(".date").bind("keyup", "change", function() {

        var startDate = $("#dateA").val();
        var endDate = $("#dateB").val();

        if (startDate.length == 7 && endDate.length == 7) compare(startDate, endDate);
        else clean();
    });

});
```